# How can I create a large matrix without running into hangs or recursion errors?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to create a probability matrix, starting by creating a 100,000 by 100,000 identity matrix. However, when I try to create this using:

```
IdentityMatrix[100000]
```

The interpreter just stops without an error message or prompt, and the variables turn blue. Why does this happen and How can I get around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you asked *Mathematica* to allocate this amount of memory (unless told otherwise, *Mathematica* tries to allocate a packed array of 64 bit integers):

```
UnitConvert[100000^2 Quantity[64, "Bits"], "Gigabytes"]
```

> Quantity[80, "Gigabytes"]

Might be a bit too much for your system.

Better use

```
IdentityMatrix[100000, SparseArray]
```

In general, I suggest to get in touch with `SparseArray` in order to learn how to construct sparse matrices efficiently.